# Wordpress taxonomy not displaying

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom taxonomy called manufacturer. It's created via an init hook. I've verified that the taxonomy exists in wordpress by print_r(get_taxonomies()); I've also verified that a post has the taxonomy by doing print_r(get_the_terms(66878, 'manufacturer')); which shows me this:

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 6957 [name] => Agilent [slug] => 6-agilent [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 6957 [taxonomy] => manufacturer [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 889 [filter] => raw ) )
```

The site was working fine up until a few days ago. I verified the DB. Innodb and nothing appears corrupted. The data in the DB looks correct. If I run this code I get no results:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'     => 'manufacturer',
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'show_count'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'   => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'title_li'     => '',
    'hide_empty'   => 0
);
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
```

or this:

```
print_r(get_terms( 'manufacturer', [
    'hide_empty' => false,
]));
```

Git shows no file changes. Also, dev and live both have this issue even though dev has not been updated data-wise in weeks. The only event that happened recently was the server got restored from an image. After the restoration, the manufacturer taxonomy was working properly. Also, this is not the only custom taxonomy that isn't functional anymore. There is at least one other one.

Answer (score 1):

I went to edit the wp-config.php file on the server and I couldn't save the file. The disk was full.

Answer (score 0):

While the docs says get_categories can be used here, I always prefer to use [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) when retrieving taxonomy terms. I don't think this will make the difference but that would be my first attempt.

Furthermore, you defined some default values, which are not needed imo:

- hierarchical is true by default
- orderby is name by default
- pad_counts is false by default

I wouldn't define what is default.

Comment: Thanks, I tried get_terms and removed those extras without effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: if you don't use any arguments at all, does it return anything then ?

Comment: get_terms returns nothing. I'm going to have to trace through the core code I think.